# How to sort these lines?

Tags: sort

I have this text:

```
menu.overlap.x: -7
menu.overlap.y: 0

!! Menu settings

menu.title.bg: Solid Flat
menu.title.bg.color: #fce855
menu.title.bg.colorTo: #daa30b
menu.title.bg.border.color: black
menu.title.text.color: #000000
menu.title.text.justify: left
menu.title.bg.interlace.color: #f5db14

!! General window settings
window.label.text.justify: center

!! focused window settings
window.active.client.color: #909498
```

If I paste it into LibreOffice Calc and use *Data* > *Sort* with the option of *Range contains column labels* unticked, I get this output:

```
!! focused window settings
!! General window settings
!! Menu settings
menu.overlap.x: -7
menu.overlap.y: 0
menu.title.bg: Solid Flat
menu.title.bg.border.color: black
menu.title.bg.color: #fce855
menu.title.bg.colorTo: #daa30b
menu.title.bg.interlace.color: #f5db14
menu.title.text.color: #000000
menu.title.text.justify: left
window.active.client.color: #909498
window.label.text.justify: center
```

I've tried `sort` with various options but I get this:

```
!! focused window settings
!! General window settings
menu.overlap.x: -7
menu.overlap.y: 0
!! Menu settings
menu.title.bg.border.color: black
menu.title.bg.color: #fce855
menu.title.bg.colorTo: #daa30b
menu.title.bg.interlace.color: #f5db14
menu.title.bg: Solid Flat
menu.title.text.color: #000000
menu.title.text.justify: left
window.active.client.color: #909498
window.label.text.justify: center
```

Which Linux command lets me sort the sample content in the same way as LibreOffice Calc does? (Blank lines are not important.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your locale settings. Try this:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort file




!! General window settings
!! Menu settings
!! focused window settings
menu.overlap.x: -7
menu.overlap.y: 0
menu.title.bg.border.color: black
menu.title.bg.color: #fce855
menu.title.bg.colorTo: #daa30b
menu.title.bg.interlace.color: #f5db14
menu.title.bg: Solid Flat
menu.title.text.color: #000000
menu.title.text.justify: left
window.active.client.color: #909498
window.label.text.justify: center
```

Or, to skip blank lines:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort file | grep .
!! General window settings
!! Menu settings
!! focused window settings
menu.overlap.x: -7
menu.overlap.y: 0
menu.title.bg.border.color: black
menu.title.bg.color: #fce855
menu.title.bg.colorTo: #daa30b
menu.title.bg.interlace.color: #f5db14
menu.title.bg: Solid Flat
menu.title.text.color: #000000
menu.title.text.justify: left
window.active.client.color: #909498
window.label.text.justify: center
```

Comment: How do I know my locale settings? I'm quite happy otherwise so how do I change it just for `sort`, and for nothing else? Does `LC_ALL=C` do that? Where can I read more about `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: @vasa1 yes, basically, the format `variable=value command` will change the value of the variable only for the specific command. So what I am suggesting will affect only the current run of `sort`. For more info on LC_ALL, see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html).